# Split string from the second occurrence of the character

Tags: ruby, string

How to split the string from the second occurrence of the character

```
str = "20050451100_9253629709-2-2"

I need the output 
["20110504151100_9253629709-2", "2"]
```

Comment: Based on your accepted answer, it seems like you are willing to settle for splitting on the final hyphen, not the strictly the 2nd. You should make sure that in your data, the 2nd is always the final.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use regular expression matching:

```
str = "20050451100_9253629709-2-2"
m = str.match /(.+)-(\d+)/
[m[1], m[2]]  # => ["20050451100_9253629709-2", "2"]
```

The regular expression matches "anything" followed by a dash followed by number digits.

Comment: thanks @hallidave. I think, this is the best in performance wise.

Comment: This answer is quite old, but could someone describe or link syntax of string match?

Answer (score 11):

There's nothing like a one-liner :)

```
str.reverse.split('-', 2).collect(&:reverse).reverse
```

It will reverse the string, split by '-' once, thus returning 2 elements (the stuff in front of the first '-' and everything following it), before reversing both elements and then the array itself.

**Edit**

```
*before, after = str.split('-')
puts [before.join('-'), after]
```

Comment: thanks @gnab. Here, you are doing very long process.. I need very shorten process

Comment: Indeed, I was simply trying to avoid unreadable regular expressions, which IMHO are kind of overkill for this rather simple problem. I updated my answer with a two-liner alternative.

Comment: To me, the best answer among all other.

Answer (score 4):

If you always have two hyphens you can get the last index of the `-`:

```
str = "20050451100_9253629709-2-2"
last_index = str.rindex('-')

# initialize the array to hold the two strings
arr = []

# get the string characters from the beginning up to the hyphen
arr[0] = str[0..last_index]
# get the string characters after the hyphen to the end of the string
arr[1] = str[last_index+1..str.length]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
"20050451100_9253629709-2-2"[/^([^-]*\-[^-]*)\-(.*)$/]
[$1, $2] # => ["20050451100_9253629709-2", "2"]
```

That will match any string, splitting it by the second occurrence of `-`.

Comment: +1 This one actually uses the 2nd occurrence and not the final one. You can make it even more succinct this way: `str.match(/^([^-]*\-[^-]*)\-(.*)$/).to_a[1..-1]`

Answer (score 2):

You could split it apart and join it back together again:

```
str = "20050451100_9253629709-2-2"
a = str.split('-')
[a[0..1].join('-'), a[2..-1].join('-')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string.gsub(/^[^-]+-[^-]+-/,'')
```

1. `^`is start
2. `[^-]`is a single character except dash
3. `[^-]+`makes item 2 one or more single characters except dashes
4. `-`is a dash
5. `[^-]+-`is a repeat of above
6. Using `gsub` removes the characters that match the pattern